# How to disable Ubercart order mail notification?

Tags: ubercart, emails

Everytime a customer places an order, the store owner gets an email with the order invoice. Where can I disable this? (the webshop is still in production)

Also, is it possible to set up a conditional to only send an e-mail when the customer has paid? (right now paypal payments works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the Rule (Configuration -> Workflow -> Rule):
**E-mail admin checkout notification.**

About the second question, you can customize the Rule:
**E-mail an order update notification** 
to email the store owner when the order changes status AND when the status is equal to "Payment received"

Hope this helps

Comment: u r very welcome!